# Why this Fuction cannot be called

Tags: python-3.x, function, bubble-sort

I have this list that I want to sort based on bubble sort, and there is a function in code **(Swap())** is refusing to work. I don't know why. there is the code

```
score = [92,95,7,5,85,55,789,47,125,3265,88,965,655,3,15,448,0,255,455]
size = len(score)
x = 0
COMPS = size - 1

def swap():
    temp = score[x + 1]
    score[x + 1] = score[x]
    score[x] = temp

# The Sort Array Function

def SortArray():
    y = 0
    while y < COMPS:
        x = 0 
        while x < COMPS:
            if score[x] > score[x + 1]:
                #This function not working.
                swap()
            x += 1
        y += 1

 #Display Array Function

def displayArray():
    x = 0
    while x < size:
        print(score[x])
        x += 1

SortArray()
displayArray()
```

but inserting the ***swap()*** code, thus the code under the ***swap()*** and replacing it underneath the **SortArray()**, below the *if condition*; just like this:

```
def SortArray():
    y = 0
    while y < COMPS:
        x = 0 
        while x < COMPS:
            if score[x] > score[x + 1]:

                #This Works
                temp = score[x + 1]
                score[x + 1] = score[x]
                score[x] = temp

            x += 1
        y += 1
```

then it works, so I want to know why the **swap()** function doesn't get called under the **SortArray()**

Comment: You don't even need that function. Swapping in Python can be done in a single-line with no explicit temp variable (not counting the implicitly created tuples): `score[x], score[x + 1] = score[x + 1], score[x]`

Comment: Using global variables in this fashion is inadvisable.

Comment: ok, but does that mean the swap() cannot be used, I thought if I wanted to call it, it should work.

Comment: @SamJereriaManuel cf my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know why the **swap()** function doesn't get called under the **SortArray()**

Actually, it IS called - which you can check by yourself adding a couple `print()` calls within or [using the step debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) - but it doesn't do what you think it should do, because you're confusing local and global variables.

In `SortArray()` you define a **local** variable named `x` (it's defined as local because you assign it in the function), and this is obviously the one you expect `swap()` to use.  But in your `swap` function, you use a variable `x` which is neither an argument of the function nor assigned within the function (both of which would make it a local variable), so it's resolved as the **global** `x` declared above.

IOW, `swap` uses the global `x` why you'd expect it to use the one which is local to `SortArray()`. This is also why the second version works, since this time it uses the proper variable.

The solution is to remove the global `x` and explicitely pass the correct value to `swap()`, ie:

```
def swap(x):
    temp = score[x + 1]
    score[x + 1] = score[x]
    score[x] = temp

def SortArray():
    y = 0
    while y < COMPS:
        x = 0 
        while x < COMPS:
            if score[x] > score[x + 1]:
                swap(x)
            x += 1
        y += 1
```

And while you're at it, you should also to the same with `score` - actually, you should avoid globals as much as possible (and believe me, you can write a **lot** of code without using globals):

```
def swap(score, x):
    temp = score[x + 1]
    score[x + 1] = score[x]
    score[x] = temp

def SortArray(score):
    comps = len(score) - 1
    y = 0
    while y < comps:
        x = 0 
        while x < comps:
            if score[x] > score[x + 1]:
                swap(score, x)
            x += 1
        y += 1


def displayArray(score):
    x = 0
    while x < len(score):
        print(score[x])
        x += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    score = [92,95,7,5,85,55,789,47,125,3265,88,965,655,3,15,448,0,255,455]
    SortArray(score)
    displayArray(score)
```

And now your functions can be used with any list or sequence. They are still totally unpythonic but that's obviously not the point here (python has one of the most optimized sort algorithm builtin anyway).

Comment: Works perfectly fine.